# Count of unique algebras with one unary operation (on finite set)

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

It's possible, that count of unique algebras (up to isomorphism) with one unary operation on set with $n$ elements is $2^n-1$?

For $n=1,2,3,4$ is this hypothesis true (I still have not verified it on the computer). Is there any counterexample, or idea for proof?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In brief: no. There are 19 algebras on 4 elements, and the pattern breaks down after that.

Instead of algebras with one unary operation, we might as well speak of nonisomorphic functions on a set of $n$ elements. The answer is then given by Theorem 6 of "The Number of Structures of Finite Relations" by Davis, R.L. A pdf is available [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1953-004-03/S0002-9939-1953-0055294-2/S0002-9939-1953-0055294-2.pdf).